# SFINAE check for operator[] is more confused than I am?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, c++17

I wrote simple check for `operator[]`, but `has_subscript_op` struct template instantiation chooses wrong overload:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <map>

template<class, class, class = void>
struct has_subscript_op : std::false_type
{ };

template<class T, class S>
struct has_subscript_op<T, S, std::void_t<decltype(&std::declval<T>()[S()])>> : std::true_type
{ };

int main()
{
    //true, nice
    std::cout << "int[][int]: " << has_subscript_op<int[], int>::value << std::endl;
    //false, nice
    std::cout << "int[][float]: " << has_subscript_op<int[], float>::value << std::endl;
    //true, nice
    std::cout << "std::string[int]: " << has_subscript_op<std::string, int>::value << std::endl;
    //true, WAT?
    std::cout << "std::map<std::string, std::string>[int]: " << has_subscript_op<std::map<std::string, std::string>, int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

I'm using GCC 6.2.0

[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05c1df0fb9e72227)

Is this GCC bug, general bug, or I made an obvious mistake somewhere?

Comment: In ~20 years I've used gcc, I found and reported maybe 5-6 bugs in the compiler. The possibility that a given compilation failure is a result of a compiler bug is extremely small.

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::string> s; auto b=s[0];` - this compiles just fine, and explains the result you're seeing. Now, why `s[0]` works, this would be a different question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Last one. Map in example should have `operator[](std::string)`, not `operator[](int)`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Good old pointer constructor taking the null pointer messing it all up ;)

Comment: Holy Fluganta Spagetmonstro, I find such implicit conversion extremely error-prone, but not much can be done I suppose... (or change `std::string` constructor from `const char* ptr` to `const char(&ref)[N]` - I don't know the consequences though)

Comment: `g++-4.8` gives also `true` for `int[][float]` (`g++-5` as the same behavior as `g++-6`). `clang++-3.7` gives the expected result for every test.

Comment: Never, ever use `S()` in a `decltype` unless it *exactly matches code you are using later*.  Use `std::declval<S>()`.

Comment: @Yakk That should be the answer. It fixes behaviour on all compilers I have access to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just drop the `&` and use `declval` for the key too:

```
template<class T, class S>
struct has_subscript_op<T, S, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::declval<S>()])>> : std::true_type {};
```

[Live example at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68f3413cd455e4f3)

Why did the check with `S()` gave the wrong result? Because in GCC, it's considered as it was `0`. A `std::string` can be constructed with a pointer, and `0` happens to be a null pointer constant.

Other compilers should not treat `S()` as it was `0` in C++14.

You can try for yourself:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> test;

// compile fine, segfault at runtime
auto a = test[0];

// compile error!
auto b = test[2]
```

The check works better with `std::declval` because it's not a `0`, neither a `2` but a plain `int`. Bonus, with `declval`, your check won't require the key to be default constructible.

Comment: Not that true. It don't convert it to reference, but a an rvalue reference and use collapsing to allow `int&`. However, `std::declval<int>()` yield the type `int&&`, which has other rules applied to.

Comment: Actually, this is a bug. Only literal zeros are null pointer constants in C++14. `S()` isn't.